# VarArrayAsPSafeArray is not available in Delphi 5.0

Tags: delphi

VarArrayAsPSafeArray is not available in Delphi 5.0
What is the equivalent of that in Delphi 5.0? I wanted exactly do the task discussed here. 
[How to convert Array of bytes to Variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143372/how-to-convert-array-of-bytes-to-variant)
Have a huge byte array and want to convert to variant. Just assignment takes upto 4 seconds!

Answer (score 5):

`VarArrayAsPSafeArray()` simply extracts the `PSafeArray` pointer from inside of a `Variant`.  You can do that directly:

```
V := VarArrayCreate([0, High(a)], varByte);
SafeArray := PSafeArray(TVarData(V).VArray);
```